# Mount a Windows DFS Namespace in Linux

Tags: centos, samba, dfs, cifs, namespaces

I've got a Windows DFS setup with a few namespaces, and I need a way of accessing them via CentOS.

Any ideas?

I've had a look at CIFS mounting, but it won't support the namespace (each separate server that hosts the content is fine, but that defeats the point of having the namespace in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

According to https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/DFS, the Linux CIFS implementation supports DFS.  Make sure you mount with type `cifs` and not type `smbfs`.  I've successfully configured a dfs namespace using Samba, and then mounted that with CIFS.

In samba.conf:

```
host msdfs = yes

[iso]
  path = /home/lars/export/iso
  browseable = no
  guest ok = yes
  writable = no

[dfs]
  path = /tmp/dfs
  browseable = no
  guest ok = yes
  writeable = no
  msdfs root = yes
```

In /tmp/dfs:

```
ln -s msdfs:\\obliquity\iso iso
```

And then:

```
# mount.cifs //obliquity/dfs /mnt -o guest
# ls /mnt
ls: cannot read symbolic link /mnt/iso: Object is remote
foo  iso
# ls /mnt/iso
a-very-import.ISO
```

Comment: It can't see the DFS namespace (ie. \\mydomain.com\share), but it can find the actual server share (\\storageserver\share).

Comment: hmm, okay, it should work according to that website. Maybe I have an old version? But then, it doesn't look like there has been any activity on that project for a while.

Comment: This thread from last year seems relevant: http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/mount-cifs-and-dfs-referrals-td2521022.html -- it suggests that the support for dfs is limited to referrals on the same server.  I've updated my answer with a working example. Closer, but still doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it can't see the DFS namespace but can see the server share, make sure your CentOS box is resolving the address (mydomain.com) correctly.

Comment: smbclient -L mydomain.com

Comment: Oops, smbclient connects fine.